# Hide UISearchBar Cancel Button

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a UISearchDisplayController and UISearchBar hooked up to my ViewController via Outlets from my nib.

I'd like to hide the cancel button so that the user never sees it. The problem is that the following code hides the button, but only after displaying it to the user for a millisecond (e.g., it flashes on the simulator and device and then disappears out of view).

```
- (void)searchDisplayControllerDidBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller 
{
    controller.searchBar.showsCancelButton = NO;
}
```

Is there a better way to hide it?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I managed to hide the "Cancel" button by subclassing `UISearchBar` and override this method:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: This works! I create a view controller with the search functions and then put the whole view controller inside a popover for iPad. Obviously, the "Cancel" button is not necessary for iPad popover, so I am looking for a non-cancle-button solution, and this one works!

Comment: This works just great! I think I tried every other way described to fix this to avoid subclassing, but wasn't able to get it done! But this fixed it flawlessly! Thanks!

Comment: This didn't work for me, I used the notification way by BFeher

Comment: You can use your view controller's `-viewWillLayoutSubviews` method instead of subclassing `UISearchBar`. That worked for me!

Comment: Why not work for me? The cancel button always missing

Comment: @maxkonovalov solution is much easier

Comment: While this worked, it caused my Caret to stop appearing after the search controller went inactive then active again.
My solution was to override the `setShowsCancelButton:animated:` method in my `UISearchBar` subclass to call `[super setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:animated];`. This allowed the cancel button to remain hidden and resolved my missing caret problem.

Answer (score 15):

I had the same issue, but fixed it a different way.

For those who can't or don't want to subclass `UISearchDisplayController`, I fixed the issue by adding a listener on `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`, and setting `[self setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:NO]` there.

In `viewWillAppear:`:

```
// Add keyboard observer:
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillAppear:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

Then you create:

```
- (void)keyboardWillAppear:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [YOUR-SEARCHBAR-HERE setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:NO];
}
```

Don't forget to add,

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

in `viewWillDisappear:`!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Will not work perfectly if Keyboard is already opened before tap.

Answer (score 7):

Similar to Nimrod's answer, you can also subclass `UISearchDisplayController` and implement the `setActive:animated:` method:

```
- (void)setActive:(BOOL)visible animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setActive:visible animated:animated];
    self.searchBar.showsCancelButton = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This seems to be a bug within Xcode. I submitted this error to Apple's bug reporting site, and they've followed up asking for more sample code and use-cases.

Thanks everyone for your attempt at solving this problem.

Comment: I am having the same issue, but in reverse. I have tried to create the UISearchDisplayController and UISearchBar using a nib file and programmatically, but instead of hiding the cancel button, I need it to be shown all the time. 

In the controller, I have the view set the button to be visible, as well as in a few of the delegate methods, but when I cancel the search, the button disappears, then reappears. Hope this get's sorted soon.

Comment: They responded saying it's a known issue and they're trying to fix it.

Comment: Glad they are aware of it, makes my search bar look a bit crap. Need to use a custom button in the meantime.

Answer (score 3):

```
class CustomSearchBar: UISearchBar {

    override func setShowsCancelButton(showsCancelButton: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: false)
    }

}

class CustomSearchController: UISearchController, UISearchBarDelegate {

    lazy var _searchBar: CustomSearchBar = {
        [unowned self] in
        let customSearchBar = CustomSearchBar(frame: CGRectZero)
        customSearchBar.delegate = self
        return customSearchBar
    }()

    override var searchBar: UISearchBar {
        get {
            return _searchBar
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This works great. But I don't understand the need for setting the search bar delegate.

Comment: Worked for me. Agree with @MarkKrenek that setting the delegate shouldn't be necessary. I removed it and still worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

Had this problem when using the `UISearchBar` with `UISearchController`. I'm using my own cancel button, as the cancel button [wasn't showing on iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33591636/72176) with `showsCancelButton = YES`, now it won't hide on iPhone with `showsCancelButton = NO`!

The following worked for me.

Set the delegate, and initial value:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // ... 
    self.searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = NO;
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
}
```

Reset `showsCancelButton` to `NO` 0.1s after the text bar begins editing.

```
#pragma mark - UISearchBarDelegate
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = NO;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked for me to hide the cancel button.

Comment: This works, but with some weird animation, showing/hiding button while presented.

Answer (score 2):

**If you want to avoid the subclassing, implement**

```
searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = false;
```

**in these two delegate methods (Do not forget to assign delegates):**

```
- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController

- (void)didPresentSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController
```

**The first one is called everytime you update the searchBar (Cancel button is visible by default) and the second one is for the first searchBar activation.**

Comment: perfect! didnt want to subclass!

Comment: Sounds promising but didn't work for me w/ iOS 12.1. Cancel button shows momentarily then disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Just based on issues I've had before have you tried setting it in:

```
- (void)searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
```

I don't know how to ask this question in your question sorry if this is out of place.

Comment: so you need to configure the cancel button when you create the UISearchDisplayController, not wait until it has begun a search.

Answer (score 0):

If the cancel button shows up when editing the search field of the search bar you could do the following; subclass the search bar and have it implement the `UITextFieldDelegate`protocol:

```
@interface CustomAlignedSearchBar : UISearchBar<UITextFieldDelegate>
```

Then implement `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` and do something like:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    [self setShowsCancelButton:self.cancelButtonShown animated:NO];
}
```

This will make sure that the cancel button will not show up.

Comment: `MLUISearchBar.m:25:37: Property 'cancelButtonShown' not found on object of type 'MLUISearchBar *'`    build error

Answer (score 0):

After UISearchDisplayController deprecated in iOS8, Apple give handle search presentation to UISearchControllerDelegate.

so you can override searchBar to hide the Cancel button, like below :

```
- (void)didPresentSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
    [searchController.searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO];
}
```

if you need hidden Cancel button from inactive state, you need set searchBar on init :

```
search = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
[search.searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

On iOS 13.0 and later, **UISearchController** has this property you can use:

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL automaticallyShowsCancelButton API_AVAILABLE(ios(13.0)); // Default YES
```