# How to override "searchBar" property in subclass of UISearchController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have the problem like this: [Hide UISearchBar Cancel Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496310/hide-uisearchbar-cancel-button)

I have subclassed `UISearchController` and `UISearchBar`, and override methods `layoutSubviews` in `UISearchBar`.

How to override `searchBar` property with custom `UISearchBar` in my custom `UISearchController`?

Update 1

To implement property with custom `UISearchBar` i do in `MyUISearchController`:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong, readonly) UISearchBar *searchBar;
```

And

```
@synthesize searchBar=_searchBar;

- (UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    return [MySearchBar new];
}
```

But `UISearchController` uses default `searchBar` anyway..

**Update**

In `h` file:

```
@interface MySearchController : UISearchController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

In `m` file:

```
@interface MySearchController () <UISearchDisplayDelegate, UISearchControllerDelegate,
UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating, SearchAutocompleteLoader>

@property UISearchController *searchController;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UITableView *searchResultTable;
@property UIView *viewForSearchBar;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger filterSettings;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *matchesLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *loading;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *foggView;

@end

- (instancetype)initWith:(UIView *)viewForSearch foggView:(UIView *)view delegate:(id)delegate andResultTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    self.viewForSearchBar = viewForSearch;
    self.searchResultTable = tableView;
    self.foggView = view;
    self.searchDelegate = delegate;
    [self configureSearchController];
    return self;
}

- (void)configureSearchController {
    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];

    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    self.searchController.delegate = self;
    self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
    [self loadFilterSettings];
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
    [self.searchController.searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO];
    //self.searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleDefault;

    [self.searchController.searchBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:(__bridge CGImageRef)([UIColor clearColor])]];
    [self.searchController.searchBar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iconSearchSettings"] forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconBookmark state:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.viewForSearchBar.frame.size.height);
    self.viewForSearchBar.tintColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
   // [self.viewForSearchBar addSubview:self.searchController.searchBar];

    self.searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.searchController.searchBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    //self.searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    [self.viewForSearchBar addSubview:self.searchController.searchBar];

    for (UIView *subView in self.searchController.searchBar.subviews) {
        if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            [subView setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
            [[(UITextField *) subView valueForKey:@"textInputTraits"] setValue:[UIColor blueColor] forKey:@"insertionPointColor"];
        }
    }

    [self.searchController setActive:YES];
    [self.searchController setActive:NO];
}
```

Comment: Is hiding Cancel button the only reason for subclass `searchBar`?

Comment: @WarifAkhandRishi Yes

Comment: @Gikas Please post some code to have a better understanding.Its very difficult to identify the issue otherwise.The solution to this problem is hiding cancel button in the viewsWillLayoutSubviews of the view controller

Comment: @AnmolKukreja Updated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`UISearchController`'s searchBar is a computed property, you have to store your custom searchBar and return it when call `searchBar`.

Here is some code in Swift:

```
var mySearchBar = MySearchBar()

override var searchBar: UISearchBar {
    get{
        return mySearchBar;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**In order to customize the searchBar property** begin the customization process by subclassing first the search bar (UISearchBar). Then, use this custom search bar in the subclass of the search controller, and at the end use both of them in the your ViewController class.

Refer this tutorial:
[UISearchController Customization](https://www.appcoda.com/custom-search-bar-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit

class MySearchController: UISearchController {

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
    }
}
```

Comment: I saw this solution in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496310/hide-uisearchbar-cancel-button
 But this not working..

Answer (score 0):

See this one tutorial for customise the UISearchBar in Swift:

[**Customise UISearchBar**](https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2016/07/hacking-uisearchbar-in-swift.html)

***Objective - C*** : Add the code in ViewDidLoad. You have already declare object of `UISearchBar`

```
[searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO];
```

***Swift*** : in ViewDidLoad

```
searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
```

[image]